# low-graphic mode changes ineffective

Tags: graphics, 12.10, configuration

My ubuntu 12.10 is booting up in "low-graphic mode". All "executable" options lead to a flashing but unresponsive prompt (scroll/num/caps-lock is dead). Pressing the power button will cause a "normal" system-reboot in most of these options. "exit to console" will not.

How can I get my system back? 
(reinstall is an option, but not ideal)

Possible troublemakers:

- started setting up systemvpn, but did not complete config. ("NOVPN" in yellow text when rebooting)
- something went wrong when I installed/removed gnome3
- my monitor is in fact EOL (takes some time for it to find its correct source, way past boot initz. x-configure is identifying it correctly though)

Comment: Please see [how to fix the system is running in low graphics mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).